# how to give file permission for android 13 in android studio using java for targetSdk 33?

Tags: java, android-studio, permissions, storage, android-sdk-manager

I'm facing a problem due to permission is not getting asked in android sdk version 33 but if you lower its version then it runs smoothly. Please help..
snippet of the code i've used i'm providing right below.
for asking permission

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };
 if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
```

I have tried this code

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };
 if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
```

and expepcting to get permission of storage for sdk 33

Comment: What type of Application you're creating?

Comment: currently creating an application which can access pdf files and images from storage for uploading.